# Css div alignment issue due to minimization

Tags: css, html

I've been working on an interface for a website. I'm stuck on a simple thing that I've spent hours and not get it fixed. I'm giving the prototype of my project. When you zoom in to page or minimize the page the alignment gets messed up. How do I fix that?

http://www.thewebblog.net/server/sosyalagDenemem

Comment: By minimize, do you mean resize the window to a smaller size?

Comment: exactly. when you make it very small, some columns simply move to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "minimization" you mean window resizing, it is because you are floating those columns.  There are two ways you could go about fixing this.

1)  Make your website responsive.  You can find **tons** of information online about this, but here are some resources to get you started:

[Ethan Marcotte's Dao of Flexibility talk](http://vimeo.com/34662135)

[Looking Beyond Common Media Query Breakpoints](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/24/beyond-common-media-query-breakpoints/)

2)  Add a `min-width` to the `<div>` that contains all of your floated elements.  Make sure the width is more than all of your floated items lined up.  This will make sure that if the window gets smaller than the container, instead of pushing those elements below each other, it will just keep the container from getting farther and create a scrollbar.

Note, this isn't necessarily the best way in terms of designing for mobile, tablet, etc., but it will certainly keep your site from breaking on "normal" desktop monitors.  If this is your only target audience, then there's no problem with it.

An example of this would be:

```
.container {
 min-width:960px;
}
```

Comment: let me check that and give you the best answer

Comment: i cant get min-width working, what might be the problem? I will work on the other solution, but for this project let's save the day for now.

Comment: all right, thanks for the help. i got it working. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are using floats and this is how they work.  As many as possible will fit on the same row and the rest will wrap below.  When the container is resized, any floats that fall off the edge are again moved below.

The easiest band-aid solution would be to add a wrapper div with a fixed `width` which is large enough to fit all of your floats without wrapping, or at least a `min-width`.  Note that this will cause a horizontal scroll-bar on any window smaller than this width.